# Get 3-letter timezone abbr for a particular date and time

Tags: android, jodatime, gregorian-calendar

I'm trying to get the 3-letter timezone abbr in Android. I used the following:

```
TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles");
timeZone.getDisplayName(true, TimeZone.SHORT);
```

This gives PDT correctly. But if I need to display this for a date in November, it doesn't give me PST. So, I tried the following:

```
Calendar newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles");
newCalendar.setTimeZone(timeZone);
newCalendar.setTime(dateInNovember);

timeZone = newCalendar.getTimeZone();
timeZone.getDisplayName(true, TimeZone.SHORT);
```

But still I get PDT. Is there something I'm missing? Or is there an alternative way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter has to be set to false if you want standard time - see [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getDisplayName-boolean-int-):

> daylight - true specifying a Daylight Saving Time name, or false
>   specifying a Standard Time name

Solution:

```
Date date = ...;
boolean dst = timeZone.inDaylightTime(date);
timeZone.getDisplayName(dst, TimeZone.SHORT);
```

Comment: Then maybe I did not understand how to use the api. Essentially, for a particular date and timezone I wanted the 3-letter abbr. So, for a date in August in Los Angeles, I need PDT, whereas for a date in November I need PST.